# CPLEX: Too Many Errors When i run OPL

Tags: cplex

I'm a beginner in CPLEX 12.8. I try to run an OPL model, it appears 51 errors includes "CPLEX cannot extract expression" "Index out of bound for array" and end with "Too many errors, giving up at 50."

this is some parts of my model that show the errors :

```
forall(p in plant, k1 in truck, k2 in truck, j1 in jobs, j2 in jobs)
  start_load[p][k1][j1]+load_time[k1][j1] <= start_load[p][k2][j2];
```

```
forall (k in truck,j in jobs)
      sum(p in plant,r in request,m in deliveries)
        x[p][r][m][k][j+1] <=
      sum(p in plant,r in request,m in deliveries)
        x[p][r][m][k][j] ;
```

```
forall(p in plant,r in request)
      travel_time_r[p][r] == (distance_r[p][r])/velocity ;
```

My .dat .mod is here :

---

How I debug this model. Thank you in advance.

EDITED

```
ct8 : forall(p1 in plant, p2 in plant, r in request, k in truck, j in jobs : j == j0)
      sum(m in deliveries : (j+1) in jobs)
        x[p1][r][m][k][j]*end_pour[k][j] <= arrive_plant[p2][k][j+1]+(base[p2][k]*travel_time_r[p][r]);
```

```
ct19 : forall(p1 in plant, p2 in plant, r1 in request, r2 in request,k in truck, j in jobs : j != j0)
        end_pour[k][j] <= 
      (sum(m1 in deliveries, m2 in deliveries : (j+1) in jobs)
        x[p1][r1][m1][k][j]*x[p2][r2][m2][k][j+1]*travel_time_r[p2][r1])+arrive_plant[p2][k][j+1];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some out of bounds you should fix. Let me give you an example:

You wrote:

```
ct3 : forall (k in truck,j in jobs)
      sum(p in plant,r in request,m in deliveries)
        x[p][r][m][k][j+1] <=
      sum(p in plant,r in request,m in deliveries)
        x[p][r][m][k][j] ;
```

but you should rather write:

```
ct3 : forall (k in truck,j in jobs)
      sum(p in plant,r in request,m in deliveries:(j+1) in jobs)
        x[p][r][m][k][j+1] <=
      sum(p in plant,r in request,m in deliveries)
        x[p][r][m][k][j] ;
```

Comment: thank you very much, but I still have errors with 2 constraints : ct8 and ct19 as showed in the main post

Comment: In ct8 and ct19 you have some products that are not linear. At https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/threadTopic?id=aa9aa3db-4fbc-4209-a767-5b5e54902cbd&ps=25 I explained how to handle that